# Auto emitting light

Tags: opengl-es, light

I am struggling trying to understand how to render an object with auto emitting light.

I use the below parameters to set the light:

```
 private float ambient = 0.3f;
 private float diffuse = 1.0f;
 private float specular = 1.0f;
 private float specularPower = 6.0f;
```

But in low light condition the object becomes darker and darker. Do we have a way to set the auto emitting light of the object so it can have the same light no matter what is the ambient light ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL ES 2.0 uses shaders - what color it renders as is entirely up to you, there is no predefined lighting model at all ...

Comment: Sure, I use:     GLES20.glUniform4f(materialParametersUniform, ambient, diffuse, specular, specularPower); with the above values. You trying to say to me that without light the color I have is the material color and so if I have a dark color with low light is just because that is the base color and If I want it to keep it white I have to set the color material to white?